# Values above line in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to plot an area plot with Plotly. Below you can see my code

```
library(plotly)

density <- density(diamonds$carat)

fig <- plot_ly(x = ~density$x, y = ~density$y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', fill = 'tozeroy')
fig <- fig %>% layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Carat'),
         yaxis = list(title = 'Density'))

fig
```

[image]

Now I want to show values on the top of this line. I tried this lines of code:

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~density$x, y = ~density$y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', fill = 'tozeroy',
               text = ~paste0(" ",round(density$y,0)),
               textposition = "outside"
               
               )
fig <- fig %>% layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Carat'),
                      yaxis = list(title = 'Density'))

fig
```

This code has not produced the results that I expected, so can anybody help me how to fix this and see values above the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the labels show up in your chart add `text` to the `mode`. Unfortunately even after playing around with different options for `textposition` I wasn't able to place the labels on "top" of the lines.

```
library(plotly)

density <- density(diamonds$carat)

fig <- plot_ly(
  x = ~ density$x, y = ~ density$y, type = "scatter", fill = "tozeroy",
  mode = "text+lines", text = ~ paste0(" ", round(density$y, 0)),
  textposition="outside"
)

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  xaxis = list(title = "Carat"),
  yaxis = list(title = "Density")
)

fig
```

[image]